# Using HTML in a jQuery string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not experienced with JS, so please excuse the presumably very beginner question.

I have this line:

```
$el.text(type + "|");
```

I need to wrap the `"|"` in span tags such as `'<span class="">|</span>'` though when I do so it simply prints out the tags as text as opposed to embedding them as HTML wraps.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Can I ask what it is that this is doing? What's `type`, where is it defined? What is `$el`? What's the end-result you're trying to achieve? What you're *asking* is quite easy, but I'm not convinced that what you're asking is necessarily the best solution to the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 5):

Use **[`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/)** to print out HTML content, text prints out plain text.

```
$el.html(type + "<span class=''>|</span>");
```

or

```
$el.html(type).append($('<span/>',{text : '|'}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically create your `span` element using this syntax:

```
var $el = $('<span>').html('|');
```

Answer (score 1):

This fiddle contains my solution. The fiddle uses a button to make it clear what is actually happening. I also added a style to the span so you can see it being added.

https://jsfiddle.net/g0n71se7/

```
$("#test").append("<span> | <span>");
```

By using the jQuery append you will insert content to the end of an element. You could alternatively use prepend to insert at the start of an element.